# Does the sequence $\langle \frac{1}{n} \rangle$ converge to $0$ under the discrete rational extension?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

> Let $\mathfrak{T}$ be the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. The **discrete rational extension** is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ given by $$\mathfrak{A}=\{U \cup Q: U \in \mathfrak{T}, Q \subset \mathbb{Q}\}$$

- Can sequences converge to rational numbers under this topology?

Comment: (eventually) constant sequences certainly can converge to rationals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following is true here:

*Claim.* Let $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, then a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $q$ if and only if it is eventually constant.

*Proof.* Clearly, if the sequence is eventually constant it converges to $q$. Conversely, if it is not eventually constant then for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we find $k > N$ such that $x_k \neq q$. Since singleton sets of rationals are open in this topology, we thus have that $\{q\}$ is an open neighborhood of $q$ that does not contain any tail of the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, therefore $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge to $q$.